# Is there a maximum size limit for valid housing?

Tags: terraria

I'm having an issue with my house after 1.2 and after researching any changes that may have been made My house is still invalid. It's all made out of stone and I've never had an issue like this before.  My houses before 1.2 have been much bigger and much smaller but were always valid

[image: House not valid]

Is there a size limit to how large a house can be?  I tried adding a row of stone from where the corner torch above the door is to the other side but still said not valid.

EDIT:  It seems I did reach some size maximum in the previous picture, but the one below shows that its suitable and the guide moved in.
[image: Smaller room occupied]

Comment: According to wiki: "This is not valid housing." : The room does not meet one or more of the following requirements: Walls, Minimum Size, Background Walls, Corruption Limit. If the corruption is at fault, usually it is only a small amount and it may be too far away to be seen on the same screen as the room. The background tiles can be tricky sometimes, and holes might be hidden by objects, be sure to check that.

Comment: I have gone over with the walls to make sure there were no holes.  and it doesn't show in that pic but I dug straight down a good long while both directly under the house floor and just off to the right of the house.  No sign of corruption.  I think the hole on the right side is somewhat close to the underworld.

Comment: Got it figured out.  I added a picture to show a decent size that can be used as a valid house.  thank you @M'vy for getting back to me so soon.  Unfortunately I haven't gotten around to testing where the line is for valid and not valid, so if anyone has a general idea of that border please comment. Thank you.

Comment: It will say "this room is corrupted" or something similar if corruption is at fault. I want to open this question back up because the "duplicate" says nothing about a maximum size. There have been a good amount of questions asked about houses being invalid when it seems most if not all have been too large, that were marked as dupes as well. Also you probably didn't have valid housing here "I tried adding a row of stone from where the corner torch above the door is to the other side" because then it wasn't tall enough.

Comment: Thank you for your input @Katustrawfic, I wanted to make a big house for the guide, so when I made the first row by the door I guess it was still to big of a room until I dropped the row down to where it is in the second picture.  I hope it will give a general idea as to how tall a room should be in order for it to be occupied in case someone wants to do a castle style with one giant room for free roaming with npc specific rooms branching off. =D

Comment: NPC's will walk into a room no matter how large it is, they just won't be able to "live" in it. So a gathering hall sort of area with branching off rooms is possbile.